# Problema con los márgenes para un h2

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema a la hora de aplicar margenes a un `h2`. Solo me hace el margen izquierdo, los demás no me los aplica. ¿Alguien sabe a que se debe? Me interesa separar el `h2` del top.

```
h2 {
  color: white; 
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 5px;
}
```

Comment: Resuelto: Para que te haga los margenes correctamente debemos poner indicar la posición absoluta. position: absolute.

Answer (score 1):

Con la posición absoluta los márgenes se aplicaran correctamente.

```
h2 {
  color: white;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 5px;
}
```

Comment: No esta mal esto de responderse a uno mismo. Soy nuevo en Stackoverflow. Espero poder aportar mucho más en este foro maravilloso. Saludos!

Comment: En realidad no hace falta que uses position absolute para que tus margenes se respeten, los margenes no son respetados para elementos con display: inline

Answer (score 1):

En principio tienes una propiedad que esta demás la cual es:

```
position: relative;
```

Ya que todos los elementos son relativos en su acomodo dependiendo donde los declares, salvo que los saques de contexto e indiques donde van a existir

Segundo:

Si lo que deseas es mover el `h2` de su elemento hermano entonces debería alcanzar con hacer lo siguiente:

```
h2 {
    color: red;   
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

¿Por qué?

- Tu estás indicando en tu respuesta que la propiedad faltante era `absolute` y sin embargo esta generará que tu elemento se salga del flujo normal de las etiquetas
- Si no has definido un ancho para tu elemento, este se perderá y solo serña en razón del contenido que escribiste en el mismo
- No tiene caso cambiar la naturaleza del elemento para moverlo, cuando tienes una regla css simple como esta: `margin-top: #px;`
- Deberías ocupar un `position: absolute;` cuando el elemento requiere una ubicación tan particular y específica que las reglas css como la propuesta no sirven para tal efecto

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Posicionamiento</title>
      <style>
        p{
          background-color: green;
        }
    h2 {
        color: red;   
        background-color: black;
        margin: 50px 100px 150px 200px;
        width: 100px;
    }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste dicta eaque laborum, dolore inventore dignissimos veniam dolorum, quos quas assumenda. Voluptatibus saepe odio, facilis dolorem voluptas reprehenderit atque non nemo.</p>
    <h2>Hola Mundo</h2>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Recuerda que este atajo de la propiedad `margin` funciona así:

```
margin: 50px 100px 150px 200px;
```

Donde:

- `50px` arriba
- `100px` a la derecha
- `150px` abajo
- `200px` a la izquierda

**Todo lo anterior debido a que....**

Si vas a declarar que tu elemento sea `position: absolute;`, entonces la forma mas lógica de acomodarlo es con:

- `top`
- `bottom`
- `left`
- `right`

**Referencia**

- [propiedad margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

Answer (score 1):

De seguro tienes un **Relative** a tu div padre para que te funcionara el margin es ponerlo a tu div hijo en **absolute**